# Finding all vectors in a list which contain a value

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I have a list of vectors of integers and I would like to have a function which gives me the indices of all vectors which contain a given integer. Something like `lapply(list, match(integer))`.

The problem with this is that this syntax is not the right way to put a function of two variables (such as `match`) to `lapply`.

What would be the right way to write it?

Comment: Can we get, like, a reproducible example and stuff?

Comment: Is that strictly necessary? Imo already posted an exhaustive answer to my question (and apparently it was not unclear to him) which I accepted. He even includes a reproducible example himself, so it does not seem to make any sense to me to write that here again. I thought that the question was pretty basic and so should not require a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty close. Here is what I would do:

```
myVectors <- sapply(1:length(myList), function(i) any(myList[[i]] == myValue))
```

This would return a logical vector that would indicate which elements of your list have the value myValue.

You could retrieve the indicies with:

```
myIndicies <- which(myVectors)
```

Though this is not usually necessary when youa already have the logical vector.

For example, you could pull the desired vectors into a new list with the following:

```
myNewList <- myList[myVectors]
```

---

As an example, give this a try on this list, where you want to find vectors with 9:

```
myList <- list(a=1:10, b=5:23, c=6, z=9:19)
sapply(1:length(myList), function(i) any(myList[[i]] == 9))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```